# How to set Http Header for Amazon S3 programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I want to set expiration date header for files which are stored in S3 by my asp.net web application.

- first case - during PutObject
  requests
- second case - update of
  expiration date once a month to
  update expiration dates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you are using Asp.net, I assume you are using the [AWS .NET SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/).

To add the `Expires`(or any other http header) when uploading the object, add it as part of the `PutObject` request.

```
var client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(AWS_Key, AWS_SecretKey);

var req = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest()
                 .WithFilePath(@"C:\myfile.txt")
                 .WithKey("myfile.txt")
                 .WithBucketName("mybucket");

req.AddHeader("expires", "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT");

client.PutObject(req);
```

To change the header on an existing object, you need to copy the object to itself.

```
var req = new Amazon.S3.Model.CopyObjectRequest()
                 .WithDirective(Amazon.S3.Model.S3MetadataDirective.REPLACE)
                 .WithSourceBucket("mybucket")
                 .WithSourceKey("myfile.txt")
                 .WithDestinationBucket("mybucket")
                 .WithDestinationKey("myfile.txt");

req.AddHeader("expires", "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT");

client.CopyObject(req);
```

**Note**: `.WithDirective(Amazon.S3.Model.S3MetadataDirective.REPLACE)` must be set in order to specify new headers. Otherwise the existing headers are just copied over.

More more info see the [.NET SDK docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will mark it as accepted after we will implement it in day or two

Comment: This answer is significantly more useful than the SDK docs on this matter: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Model_S3Request_AddHeader.htm "Adds the header to the collection of headers for the request."

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the **AWS SDK 2.X** then the "AddHeader" method is no longer available. To add a header you just modify the *header* collection directly.

`req.Headers["expires"] = "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT";`

Here is the modified example Geoff used above:

```
var client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(AWS_Key, AWS_SecretKey);

var req = PutObjectRequest req= new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = "mybucket",
    Key = "myfile.txt",
    FilePath = @"C:\myfile.txt"
};

req.Headers["expires"] = "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT";

client.PutObject(req);
```

To change the header it's the same way:

```
var req = new Amazon.S3.Model.CopyObjectRequest()
{
    MetadataDirective = S3MetadataDirective.REPLACE,
    SourceBucket = "mybucket",
    SourceKey = "myfile.txt",
    DestinationBucket = "mybucket",
    DestinationKey = "myfile.txt"
};

req.Headers["expires"] = "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT";

client.CopyObject(req);
```

Comment: Careful when you change the headers because your code above will also change the permission to fully private if it was, for instance, public read. To keep the same `CannedACL` specify it in the request

Answer (score 3):

For AWSSDK.S3 V3.* its works like this:

```
request.Headers.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
```